# CSS code to margin space above text Only without effecting the background?

Tags: html, css, text, alignment, margin

I have a class that has both a background image and text. I'm trying to figure out a way to manipulate the space above the Text Only, using the "margin" tag will change the position of the entire thing (image + text). I need to control the text only.

*text-indent* gives me some control over the horizontal spacing, but I need something to have more control over the space above and below the text only if such thing exists.

Here's the CSS class:

```css
.contactb { float:left; margin:0 5px 0 0; padding:0 0; background:url(images/contact_b.png) top no-repeat; display:block; width:108px; height:57px; font-family: 'hand-webfont'; color:black; font-size:17px; }
```

Here's the HTML code:

```html
<li><a href="contact.html" class="contactb">Contact</a></li>
```

Comment: please include the relevant HTML and CSS so that we can have a better understanding of the question. That said, have you tried using `padding` instead of `margin`?

Comment: I added both, thanks for replying. Maybe there's something wrong with my code (still a beginner here), but margin and padding both effect the background image as well which messes up the layout, I need to control the text alone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're simply looking for 'padding':

```css
.myClass {
    padding-top: 10px
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, in my case the padding also effects the entire image as well which messes up my layout, I'll add the code in the question now.

Comment: @jos - any padding you add to the top or bottom must be subtracted from the height you have set on the 'a' tab. THis is how the box model works in CSS. so if you set padding-top:10px and you have your height set to 57px you should reduce your height to be 47px. This theory alos applies to the width of an element of you're setting left/right padding.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation man, the height thing was what confused me and adjusting its value solved the issue. I can't vote up your answer since I don't have enough reps but I sure will accept it now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example of what I think you're trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/yhV78/

The trick:

1. create one div that contains your background image (in my case, the background is the bunny)
2. create an inner div (or series of divs) that contains your content. You can position them either by adjusting the padding on the inner divs or by a combination of relative and absolute positioning.

Comment: I'm trying to do this for an unordered list, I think creating a div for each will only confuse me more and make it over complicated, but the idea might be useful to me for something else, thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to combine padding with [background-origin](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-origin.asp)...
Though, it is supported only in CSS 3 capable browsers (not in older Internet Explorer versions: before [Internet Explorer 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_9))

This

**background-origin:border-box;**

plus appropriate **padding** works fine for me...
(The default value for background-origin is padding-box, which is the reason, padding alone doesn't work for you...)